# Getting constant value inside a cshtml file by Roslyn library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, roslyn, microsoft.codeanalysis

I have an ASP.NET Core v5.0 Roslyn project. I want to get the value of a constant variable inside a `cshtml` file. This is a part of my `cshtml`:

```
@{
    bool isPermitted = !await HasPermission(MyConstantValue);
}
```

`MyConstantValue` is identified in another file not in `cshtml`:

```
public static class Permissions
{
    public const string MyConstantValue = "PermissionName";
}
```

And here is what I have tried so far:

```
var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(cshtmlCode);
var root = syntaxTree.GetRoot();
var methodInvocations = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>();

foreach (var invocation in methodInvocations)
{
    var memberAccess = invocation.Expression as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax;
    
    if (memberAccess != null && memberAccess.Name.Identifier.ValueText == "HasPermission")
    {
        var argument = invocation.ArgumentList.Arguments.FirstOrDefault();
        if (argument != null)
        {
            var argumentValue = argument.Expression.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

After running this code `argumentValue` becomes `MyConstantValue`. But I need to get `PermissionName`.

Actually I do this at the backend side by `semanticModel.GetConstantValue` method. But here I tried several ways including some `semanticModel` examples did not work. I get "unspecified" value in `argumentValue`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a full [mre] to play with?